# Python - Removing primes that contain an even number from a list of primes

Tags: python, list, loops, primes

I want to write a programme which removes all the primes which contain an even digit from a list of primes.

Can anyone explain why this code returns the correct result if the limit = 200, but returns an error if the limit = 300?

```
def odd_primes(limit):
    r = list(gen_primes(limit))
    for i in r[:]:
        for j in str(i):
            if int(j)%2==0:
                r.remove(i)
return r
```

Where `gen_primes(limit)` is a generator which returns all primes under limit.

If limit = 200 it returns:

```
[3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 31, 37, 53, 59, 71, 73, 79, 97, 113, 131, 137, 139, 151, 157, 173, 179, 191, 193, 197, 199]
```

But if the limit is 300 I get this error:

```
line 19, in odd_primes
r.remove(i)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Why is this the case? And how can I correct it?

Comment: share complete code including gen_primes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code may remove the same element multiple times, if it contains multiple even digits. The first such prime is 223, which is why your code fails when `limit` is 300, but not when it's 200.

This is the offending code:

```
for j in str(i):
    if int(j)%2==0:
        r.remove(i)
```

Instead, just remove the prime once. For example:

```
for j in str(i):
    if int(j)%2==0:
        r.remove(i)
        break
```

Or perhaps more stylishly:

```
if any(int(j)%2 == 0 for j in str(i)):
    r.remove(i)
```

Comment: @ggordon if this answers your question, you might like to accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If your prime has two even numbers your routine tries to remove it twice. I would do:

```
def odd_primes(limit):
    r = list(gen_primes(limit))
    for i in r[:]:
        for j in str(i):
            if j in '02468':
                r.remove(i)
                break
    return r
```